# How can I solve rational integrals if I cannot factor the denominator?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

Here is this integral and I dont know how do I start it I tried factoring the denominator but its not possible what should I do ?

$\int \frac{1}{x^2+x+1} dx$

Comment: $x^2+x+1= \left(x+\frac 12\right)^2 + \frac 34 = \left(x+\frac 12\right)^2 +\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^2$

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%2Bx%2B1%7D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this you can [complete the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)

$I =\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{x^2+x+1} dx$

$I = \displaystyle \int\dfrac{1}{(x+\frac12)^2+\frac34}\,dx$

$I = \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\arctan\bigg(\frac{x+\frac12}{\frac{\sqrt3}2}\bigg)+C$

Comment: but this is very hard :'( is there another way

Comment: This by far is the easiest way to solve it .

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{(x-2)(x^2+1)^2} dx$ could you help me with this ?

Comment: @EndritShabani for cases like that you can use [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) .[Here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/PartialFractions.aspx) is a link to examples

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to solve after you've noticed that$$\frac1{x^2+x+1}=\frac1{\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}.$$